# Calculate in a custom column by using subdate to get the previous day

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, window-functions

I am trying to use the subdate method in mysql but I can't get what I want...

Consider I have the below table :

Table:

```
id    created_at    value
1     2019-03-19    50
2     2016-03-20    100
3     2016-03-21    87
```

I would like to create a view which will display the 3 columns and add one custom which is basically the difference between the current value and the one at the previous day.

In the example, my view output should be:

```
id    created_at    value    diff
1     2019-03-19    50       0
2     2016-03-20    100      50
3     2016-03-21    87       -13
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Which MySQL version as MySQL 8 makes this more easy with LEAD/LAG otherwise you have to simulate it with MySQL user variables or a corelated subquery

Comment: I am using mysql workbench 8.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, you can use `lag()`:

```
select 
    t.*,
    coalesce(value - lag(value) over(order by created at), 0) diff
from mytable t
```

In earlier versions, you can self-join the table and use a `not exists` condition with a correlated subquery to get the previous record:

```
select
    t.*,
    coalesce(t.value - t1.value, 0) diff
from mytable t
left join mytable t1 
    on t1.created_at < t.created_at
    and not exists(
        select 1
        from mytable t2
        where t2.created_at < t.created_at and t2.created_at > t1.created_at
    )
```

Comment: Thank you! This works for me using the second part of your answer. You did a small typo in this answer: "coalsece". If you can please edit it

Comment: @WilliamW: welcome! Thanks for spotting the typo, I edited my answer accordingly.